# I want to reduce my SQL Query on big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, query-optimization

I want to fetch data  from bigQuery database but I get an error 
=>The query is too large. The maximum query length is 256.000K characters, including comments and white space characters.
i will show a part of query which i repeated 21 times

```
WITH data AS 
(
 SELECT
 IFNULL(department, 'UNKNOWN_DEPARTMENT') AS dept,


> 'C7s'

 AS campus,
 COUNTIF(task.taskRaised.raisedAt.milliSeconds BETWEEN 1542565800000 AND 1543170599999) AS taskCount_0,
 COUNTIF(task.taskRaised.raisedAt.milliSeconds BETWEEN 1542565800000 AND 1543170599999 

 AND IF (task.deadline.currentEscalationLevel NOT IN 
 (
 'ESC_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT'
 )
, task.deadline.currentEscalationLevel, 'NOT_ESCALATED') NOT IN 
 (
 'NOT_ESCALATED'
 )
) AS escCount_0,
 COUNTIF(task.taskRaised.raisedAt.milliSeconds BETWEEN 1541961000000 AND 1542565799999) AS taskCount_1,
 COUNTIF(task.taskRaised.raisedAt.milliSeconds BETWEEN 1541961000000 AND 1542565799999 
 AND IF (task.deadline.currentEscalationLevel NOT IN 
 (
 'ESC_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT'
 )
, task.deadline.currentEscalationLevel, 'NOT_ESCALATED') NOT IN 
 (
 'NOT_ESCALATED'
 )
) AS escCount_1,
 COUNTIF(task.taskRaised.raisedAt.milliSeconds BETWEEN 1541356200000 AND 1541960999999) AS taskCount_2,
 COUNTIF(task.taskRaised.raisedAt.milliSeconds BETWEEN 1541356200000 AND 1541960999999 
 AND IF (task.deadline.currentEscalationLevel NOT IN 
 (
 'ESC_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT'
 )
, task.deadline.currentEscalationLevel, 'NOT_ESCALATED') NOT IN 
 (
 'NOT_ESCALATED'
 )
) AS escCount_2 
 FROM

>  `nsimplbigquery.TaskManagement.C7s_*`

 WHERE
 _TABLE_SUFFIX IN 
 (
 '2018_47_11',
 '2018_45_11',
 '2018_46_11'
 )
 AND IFNULL(department, 'UNKNOWN_DEPARTMENT') IN 
 (
 'ENGG_AND_MAINT_DEPARTMENT',
 'FNB_DEPARTMENT',
 'TELECOM_DEPARTMENT',
 'IT_DEPARTMENT',
 'BILLING_AND_INSURANCE',
 'HOUSEKEEPING_DEPARTMENT'
 )
 AND task.taskRaised.raisedAt.milliSeconds BETWEEN 1541356200000 AND 1543170599999 
 GROUP BY
 dept
)
,
mainQuery AS 
(
 SELECT
 dept,
 campus,
 SUM(taskCount_0) AS taskCount_0,
 SUM(escCount_0) AS escCount_0,
 CAST(SAFE_DIVIDE(SUM(escCount_0), SUM(taskCount_0)) * 10000 AS INT64) AS escPerc_0,
 SUM(taskCount_1) AS taskCount_1,
 SUM(escCount_1) AS escCount_1,
 CAST(SAFE_DIVIDE(SUM(escCount_1), SUM(taskCount_1)) * 10000 AS INT64) AS escPerc_1,
 SUM(taskCount_2) AS taskCount_2,
 SUM(escCount_2) AS escCount_2,
 CAST(SAFE_DIVIDE(SUM(escCount_2), SUM(taskCount_2)) * 10000 AS INT64) AS escPerc_2 
 FROM
 data 
 GROUP BY
 ROLLUP (campus, dept)
)
SELECT
 dept,
 campus,
 taskCount_0,
 escCount_0,
 escPerc_0,
 taskCount_1,
 escCount_1,
 escPerc_1,
 taskCount_2,
 escCount_2,
 escPerc_2 
FROM
 mainQuery 
WHERE
 campus IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY
 CASE
 WHEN
 dept IS NULL 
 THEN
 1 
 ELSE
 0 
 END
 ASC, dept ASC, campus ASC;
```

This is the query which I repeat so many times so can due to I have so many ids Where C7s i changed with following ids

C7z,
C7u,
H0B,
IDp,
ITR,
C7i,
C7j,
C7k,
C7l,
C7m,
C7o,
C71,
C7t,
F6qZ,
C7w,
GIui,
Fs,
C70,
C7p,
C7r
if you see my explainantion i quote a line this nsimplbigquery.TaskManagement.C7s_*
so at next query the table names is changed
like

> nsimplbigquery.TaskManagement.C7z_*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repeating your whole SELECT statement 21 times, rather use below approach. You will have 3x21=63 entries in the that list for _TABLE_SUFFIX - but you will be able to get around your issue with query length

```
FROM `nsimplbigquery.TaskManagement.*` 
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX IN (
  'C7s_2018_47_11',
  'C7s_2018_45_11',
  'C7s_2018_46_11',
  'C7z_2018_47_11',
  'C7z_2018_45_11',
  'C7z_2018_46_11',
  'C7u_2018_47_11',
  'C7u_2018_45_11',
  'C7u_2018_46_11',
  ...
  ...
  ... 
  'C7r_2018_47_11',
  'C7r_2018_45_11',
  'C7r_2018_46_11',
  )
```